# Strange SeekBar behaivor after setThumb

Tags: android, android-widget

I have strange problem, when I change SeekBar's thumb like

```
    final int drawableId = R.drawable.slider;
    final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    d.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d
            .getIntrinsicHeight()));
        seek.setThumb(d);
```

My SeekBar started to behaive strangde, for example I click on some other widget seek change value, I scroll in scrollView it change value. Did anyone have the similar problem ?